# Can macros match against constant arguments instead of literals?

Tags: macros, rust

Given the [macro matching example](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/macros.html#matching), this shows how macros can match an argument.

I've made very minor changes here to use numbers:

```
macro_rules! foo {
    (0 => $e:expr) => (println!("mode X: {}", $e));
    (1 => $e:expr) => (println!("mode Y: {}", $e));
}

fn main() {
    foo!(1 => 3);
}
```

Works, printing: `mode Y: 3`

However I would like to use a constant as an argument, can this be made to work:

```
const CONST: usize = 1;

macro_rules! foo {
    (0 => $e:expr) => (println!("mode X: {}", $e));
    (1 => $e:expr) => (println!("mode Y: {}", $e));
}

fn main() {
    foo!(CONST => 3);
}
```

Is this possible in Rust?

---

Note, using a regular `match` statement isn't usable for me, since in my code each branch resolves to different types, giving an error.
So I'm specifically interested to know if a constant can be passed to a macro.

Comment: You say "each branch resolves to different types".  Can you give an example?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**No.**

Macros operate on the Abstract *Syntax* Tree, so they reason at the syntactic level: they reason about *tokens* and their *spelling*.

For example:

```
fn main() {
    let v = 3;
}
```

In this case, the AST will look something like:

```
fn main
    \_ let-binding v
        \_ literal 3
```

If you ask a macro whether `v` is `3`, it will look at you funny, and wonder why you would try comparing a variable name and a literal.

Comment: I think it's not *exactly* the AST - macros are given not-fully-parsed tokens (since, of course, the macro defines partly how to parse them).  I say not-fully-parsed rather than unparsed since you do have `$e:expr`.

Comment: @ChrisEmerson: Yes, it's a bit looser than this.

Answer (score 4):

I'm fairly sure the answer is "no"; at macro expansion time all you have are token trees - expansion happens before evaluation, or even type inference/checking.

Answer (score 1):

```
const CONST: usize = 0;

macro_rules! foo {
    ($i:ident => $e:expr) => {
        if $i == 0 {
            println!("mode X: {}", $e);
        } else if $i == 1 {
            println!("mode Y: {}", $e);
        }
    };
}

fn main() {
    foo!(CONST => 3);
}
```

If you want use identifier in macro it needs to be `ident` tag and you can use `if`, `else if` blocks instead of `match`.

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: Thanks for warning.