# How to create a constant string literal in Rust?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to define a constant format string that is used in a number of places with the `format!` macro.

I've tried something like:

```
const FORMAT_A: &'static str = "a: {}";
static FORMAT_B: &'static str = "b: {}";

fn main() {
    format!(FORMAT_A, "a");
    format!(FORMAT_B, "b");
}
```

However, this fails to compile with:

```
error: format argument must be a string literal.
 --> src/main.rs:5:13
  |
5 |     format!(FORMAT_A, "a");
  |             ^^^^^^^^

error: format argument must be a string literal.
 --> src/main.rs:6:13
  |
6 |     format!(FORMAT_B, "b");
  |             ^^^^^^^^
```

Is there another way I should be defining a constant string literal to use with `format!`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39349286/can-macros-match-against-constant-arguments-instead-of-literals

Comment: But you can define them as macros: `macro_rules! FORMAT_A { () => { "a: {}" }; }` and `format!(FORMAT_A!(), "a")`.

Comment: Also related: [println! error: format argument must be a string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27734708/println-error-format-argument-must-be-a-string-literal).

Comment: @DaveChallis One of the other questions had a link to this but I think it's worth repeating here: [meaning of the term "literal"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literal_%28computer_programming%29)