# Rust macros: Calling function dependent on expression

Tags: rust, rust-macros

I have a three different functions, of which I want to call one based on a macro argument. This argument should be pre-processed, which is why I thought I need to write it as `expr`. However, I can't seem to find a way to distinguish different cases for an `expr` in a macro. Here is my code:

```
fn func_100(){
    println!("Func 100!");
}
fn func_200(){
    println!("Func 200!");
}
fn func_300(){
    println!("Func 300!");
}

macro_rules! generate_func_call {
    (100) => {
        func_100();
    };
    (200) => {
        func_200();
    };
    (300) => {
        func_300();
    }
}

macro_rules! generate_func_call_wrapper {
    ($func: ident, $number: expr) => {
        fn $func(){
            println!("{:?}", $number / 100);
            generate_func_call!($number);
        }
    };
}

generate_func_call_wrapper!(f1,100);
generate_func_call_wrapper!(f2,200);
generate_func_call_wrapper!(f3,300);

fn main(){
    f1();
}
```

which generates the following compile time error:

```
    generate_func_call!($number);
                        ^^^^^^^ no rules expected this token in macro call
```

How can I fix this program so that calls a different function based on the `$number` expression?

Comment: TBH the Rust compiler is pretty good in optimizing, so if you are using constants in an `if` expression it will eliminate that for you, so it has no impact on runtime.

Comment: Very related (if not dup): https://stackoverflow.com/q/39349286

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can macros match against constant arguments instead of literals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39349286/can-macros-match-against-constant-arguments-instead-of-literals)

Answer (score 6):

You can see the macro expansion by calling `cargo +nightly rustc --profile=check -- -Zunstable-options --pretty=expanded` or using [cargo-expand](https://github.com/dtolnay/cargo-expand)

```sh
fn f1() {
    {
        ::std::io::_print(::std::fmt::Arguments::new_v1(
            &["", "\n"],
            &match (&(100 / 100),) {
                (arg0,) => [::std::fmt::ArgumentV1::new(arg0, ::std::fmt::Debug::fmt)],
            },
        ));
    };
    ();
}
```

You can see the last `();` which should have been `func_100()`

This is beacuse there is no token rule in `generate_func_call` of type `($number: expr)` i.e. there is no rule which matches the expansion. This is beacuse `$number` is not replaced by `100` as you would expect in a function. The macro simply creates more rust code based on the [fragment types](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/macros-by-example.html) it receives, it does not try to evaluate anything.

Change the code to:

```rust
macro_rules! generate_func_call {
    ($number: expr) => {
        match $number {
            100 => func_100(),
            200 => func_200(),
            300 => func_300(),
            _ => (),
        }
    };
}
```

And finally `();` changes to:

```rust
match 300 {
    100 => func_100(),
    200 => func_200(),
    300 => func_300(),
    _ => (),
};
```

You don't have to worry about an extra jump statement or such, it's gets optimized as `300` is compile time constant. and it just changes into `func_300()`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's simply not supported.

[Simmilar Issue #1](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/25875)
[Simmilar Issue #2](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/41472)

A possible workaround is to match against the literal in the first macro, like in this [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3e083470934dc1b2c3959e45ab3a65be). Although that just introduces more code repetition.

In the future it might be possible to do this using the `const fn` feature like in this [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8a3c5bd77315dbc3e35d5e87f1a69687). But you'll have to wait for the [feature to be implemented](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/57563).

Right now I'd advise to simply match against the value at runtime using a regular `match`.