# How to execute a function with given name?

Tags: rust

I have multiple functions that all follow the same naming scheme:

```
fn function1() {
   ...
}

fn function2() {
   ...
}

fn function3() {
   ...
}
```

I would like to execute `function1`, `function2` or `function3` depending on a variable, without manually having to use pattern matching.

The following pattern matching has the expected behavior but requires to hardcode every single value:

```
fn execute() {
   let function_number = 2;

   match function_number {
      1 => function1(),
      2 => function2(),
      3 => function3()
   };
}
```

I would like instead to do something that would look like this:

```
fn execute() {
   let function_number = "2";

   call("function" + function_number);
}
```

Comment: I think your `match` is perfectly reasonable. You could [write a macro](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55802372/2970947), but it'll look very similar to what you've already got.

Comment: The `match` is perfectly working for small cases, but seems to be quite repetitive for tens of functions. I was just wondering if there were a better way to do so, but I guess not.

Comment: Yes. I read your question. You want an `eval` function. But rust is a compiled language.

Comment: It feels like this would be a usecase for trait implementations or a level of indirection over the function number, could you give more info on what you're trying to do?
ref: https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: Function names only exist at compile time. At run time, there are no function names, so it's impossible to look up a function by name at runtime. Moreover, even for languages like Python that do support runtime reflection, you should keep data and source code identifiers separate. There's always a better solution. As Folling said, explain the problem you want to solve, and we may be able to help.

Comment: My entire program is made of multiple functions called `function1`, etc. The main function uses `io::stdin()` to input a valid number, corresponding to a function to execute.
I understand that no such thing as an `eval` could work in Rust since it is a compiled language. The difference between my expected behavior and `eval` would be that somehow, the compiler could know at compilation time what function I am referring to, but it seems overcomplicated.

Comment: I'm not sure how rust works, but in C I would have an array of function pointers, which you could just index into. Any time something is named ...1, ...2, ...3, it's code smell for an array.

Comment: @RedRapious Use meaningful function names. Else you'll end up with `function5_and_3quarters` and that's just madness.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch This is only for a very specific use case. Each function is the solution to a given problem identifiable by a number. I would not use this in any other situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this execute function to make it dynamic:

```rust
fn execute(function_number: &str) {
    // Convert the function_number to an integer
    let function_number: u32 = function_number.parse().expect("Invalid number");
   
    // Define a vector of function pointers
    let functions: Vec<fn()> = vec![function1, function2, function3];

    // Check if the function_number is within the valid range
    if function_number <= functions.len() as u32 {
        functions[(function_number - 1) as usize]();
    } else {
        println!("Invalid function number");
    }
}
```

In main function you can easily call this function

```rust
fn main() {
    let fn_number = "2";
    execute(fn_number);
}
```

Comment: That is actually quite smart. I will implement that instead, even though it does not exactly answer my question.

Comment: Prefer `if let Some(function) = functions.get(function_number as usize - 1) { function() }` rather than manual checking the range + indexing. Also your code panics if `function_number` is 0, maybe use `function_number.checked_sub(1)` if you want to ensure the index is valid without manually checking. Also `function_number` should be a `usize` instead, since it's an index.

Comment: @FilipeRodrigues Yes exactly, you are right,  we can modify it as per your suggestions. I actually just tried to answer the question.

Answer (score 3):

This is not exactly what you requested since you still have to add code for each function, but the code can be near the function so it is harder to forget. You can even create a macro that wraps the function and automatically creates the corresponding entry.

Using the [`linkme`](https://github.com/dtolnay/linkme) crate, we can define a slice of functions and their names:

```rust
#[linkme::distributed_slice]
static FNS: [(u32, fn())] = [..];

fn find_function(function_number: u32) -> Option<fn()> {
    FNS.iter().find(|&&(n, _)| n == function_number).map(|&(_, f)| f)
}
```

Then you define functions like:

```rust
#[linkme::distributed_slice(FNS)]
static FUNCTION_1: (u32, fn()) = (1, function_1);
fn function_1() {}
```

Or even with a closure:

```rust
#[linkme::distributed_slice(FNS)]
static FUNCTION_1: (u32, fn()) = (1, || {});
```