# Why can I not store the result of concat! in a constant and use that constant with include_str?

Tags: rust

The following doesn't compile:

```
pub fn main() {
    const IMG_PATH: &str = concat!("a", "b", "c");
    let img = include_str!(IMG_PATH);
}
```

It fails with an error that `include_str` requires a string literal:

```
error: argument must be a string literal
 --> src/main.rs:3:28
  |
3 |     let img = include_str!(IMG_PATH);
  |                            ^^^^^^^^
```

Constructing the string inside the `include_str!` seems to fix the compiler issue — it then complains about the path not being present in the filesystem so I suspect the former is resolved)

```rust
// works 
let img = include_str!(concat!("a", "b", "c"));
```

Why is this happening? As far as I understand `concat` operates statically and doesn't require doing anything at runtime. `IMG_PATH` is also a constant that should also be allocated at compile-time.

rustc 1.43.1 (8d69840ab 2020-05-04)

Comment: Macros are evaluated well before any understanding of what a constant is.

Comment: You're not going to be able to mix runtime code and macro code like this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can macros match against constant arguments instead of literals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39349286/can-macros-match-against-constant-arguments-instead-of-literals)

Comment: [The duplicates applied to your situation](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5ebfbfb113881fba0a16f97184c39e53)